# How to identify optimal parameters for cvCanny for polygon approximation

Tags: c, opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection, edge-detection

This is my source image (ignore the points, they were added manually later):

[image]

My goal is to get a rough polygon approximation of the two hands. Something like this:

[image]

I have a general idea on how to do this; I want to use [`cvCanny`](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~bouakaz/OpenCV-0.9.5/docs/ref/OpenCVRef_ImageProcessing.htm#decl_cvCanny) to find edges, [`cvFindContours`](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~bouakaz/OpenCV-0.9.5/docs/ref/OpenCVRef_ImageProcessing.htm#decl_cvFindContours) to find contours, and then [`cvApproxPoly`](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~bouakaz/OpenCV-0.9.5/docs/ref/OpenCVRef_StructAnalysis.htm#decl_cvApproxPoly).

The problem I'm facing is that I have no idea on how to properly use `cvCanny`, particularly, what should I use for the last 3 parameters (threshold1&2, apertureSize)? I tried doing:

```
cvCanny(source, cannyProcessedImage, 20, 40, 3);
```

but the result is not ideal. The left hand looks relatively fine but for the right hand it detected very little:

[image]

In general it's not as reliable as I'd like. Is there a way to guess the "best" parameters for Canny, or at least a detailed explanation (understandable by a beginner) of what they do so I can make educated guesses? Or perhaps there's a better way to do this altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe one of the easiest solution is make Otsu thresholding on grayscale image, find contours on the binary image and than approximate them. Here's code:

```
Mat img = imread("test.png"), gray;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
vector<vector<Point2i> > contours;

cvtColor(img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
threshold(gray, gray, 0, 255, THRESH_OTSU);
findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

for(size_t i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
{
    approxPolyDP(contours[i], contours[i], 5, false);
    drawContours(img, contours, i, Scalar(0,0,255));
}

imshow("result", img);
waitKey();
```

And this is result:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It seems you have to lower your thresholds.

The Canny algorithm work on the hysteresis threshold: it selects a contour if at least a pixel is as bright as the max threshold, and takes all the connected contour pixels if they are above the lower threshold.

Papers recommend to take the two thresholds in a scale of 2:1 oe 3:1 (by example 10 and 30, or 20 and 60, etc). For some applications, a threshold determined manually and hardcoded is enough. It may your case, too. I suspect that if you lower your thresholds, you will have good results, because the images are not that complicated.

A number of methods to automatically determine the best canny thresholds have been proposed. Most of them rely on gradient magnitudes to estimate the best thresholds.

**Steps:**

- Extract the gradients (Sobel is a good option)
- You can convert it to uchar. Gradients teoretically can have greater numerical values than 255, but that's ok. opencv's sobel returns uchars.
- make a histogram of the resulting image.
- take the max threshold at the 95th percentile of your histogram, and the lower as high/3.
- You should probably adjust the percentile value depending on your app, but the results will be much more robust than a hardcoded hig and low values

**Note:** An excellent threshold detection algorithm is implemented in Matlab. It is based on the idea above, but a bit more sophisticated.

**Note 2**: This methods will work if the contours and illumination do not varies a lot between image areas. If the contours are crisper on one part of the image, then you need locally adaptive thresholds, and that's another story. But looking at you pics, it should not be the case.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, I now understand it better. +1. I picked the other answer as the accepted one because it's simpler in my case.